# Color pulse broken on linear gradient. How to fix "@keyframe" to pulse background of a button?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm making an Aqua button (from Mac OS X) and one of the many things I must fix is the button pulse, which seems to be very hard to find one to implement that actually (kinda) works

However, I found a (quarter-working) fix that "technically" pulses, but that doesn't fix the new problem of making the entire background pulse instead of the background size. It moves the color of choice (specifically the `background`) of the `@keyframe` up and down. So I want the entire background of the button to pulse instead of `background-size`. [The background keyframe for clarity here (focus on the top one).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3RJZ.gif)

Here's the CSS code:

```css
@keyframes color {
    from {
        background-size:50% 50%;
      }
    to {
        background-size:100% 100%;
      }
  }
:root {
    --confirm: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 36, 197),rgb(196, 201, 207));
    --cancel: linear-gradient(#AAAAAA,#FFFFFF);
    --altconfirm: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 100, 240),rgb(200, 200, 210))
}
button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 125px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 13px 25px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 10px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 1rem;
    padding: .8rem 2rem;
    position: relative;
    transition: all ease .3s;
}
button:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 13px 25px rgba(255,255,255,.7), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 10px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transform: scale(1.001);
}
button::before {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.8) 7%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%);
    border-radius: 125px;
    content:'';
    height: 97.5%;
    left: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    transition: all ease .3s;
    width: 90%;
}
button:active{
    box-shadow: inset 0 13px 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 10px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transform: scale(1);
}
button::before:active{
    box-shadow: inset 0 13px 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.418), 0 10px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
    transform: scale(1);
}
button.confirm {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 36, 197),rgb(196, 201, 207));
    animation-name: color;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
button.cancel {
    background: var(--cancel);
    border: 1.7px solid #AAA;
    color: #000;
}
```

And the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="confirm" style="background-color: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 36, 197),rgb(196, 201, 207))">Push Button</button><br>
    <button class="cancel">Push Button</button><br>
    <p>EEE</p>
</body>
</html>
```